# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'permissions') discord.js V13

Tags: discord, discord.js

I try to do a anti link bot discord that only who have the `VIEW_AUDIT_LOG` permission can send link this is my code :

```
client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    const { member } = message;
    let blacklisted = ['http://', 'www.', 'https://'];
    let foundInText = false;

    if(!member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_AUDIT_LOG)) {
        for (var i in blacklisted) {
      
            if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(blacklisted[i].toLowerCase())) foundInText = true;
          }
          if (foundInText) {
              const logembed = new MessageEmbed()
              .setColor("DARK_AQUA")
              .addField(' with message :', ` ${message.content} `, true)
              
              if(!message.member.roles.cache.has("929434049011941386")) {
                  message.guild.channels.cache.get('941704496185221221').send({ content: `<@${message.author.id}> tried to send links in <#${message.channel.id}>`, embeds: [logembed] });;
                  message.delete();
                  message.channel.send("No links here, " + `${message.author}`);
              }
          }
    }

});
```

but it give this error when he delete a message with link :

```
   if(!member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_AUDIT_LOG)) {
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'permissions')
```

Comment: It means, `member` is `null`. What intents are enabled?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros all 3 intent presence & server members & message content

Comment: at the top of the messageCreate event handler use a ```console.log(message)``` and show the results.  this should help you understand why member isn't populating.

Comment: I said message, not member.  see what you're getting from message....

Comment: @G-Force https://sourceb.in/czL0AbZW1J

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros in text channel

Comment: @RyuuPotato Could you also add how you initialise your client?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros this is the index.js https://sourceb.in/jXFaStKPuD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so here's my guess....you're hitting this event handler twice or more times...the first time is the message the user typed.  you will get their member info, if you `console.log(message.member)`.  The second time through, you'll be getting another event, which is the message(s) you send as a handler.

So the easy solution is to add something like this at or near the top of this event handler:

```
    if (message.author.bot) return;
```

this basically tests to see if it's a bot or not that's calling your event.  It's also good hygiene to ensure you're not accepting/reacting to other bots, which could result in spam you likely don't want.